# I have a error in Processing 3.0 for Arduino

Tags: arduino

I have a problem with procesing 3.0 for Arduino. It always appears this error:

> "The size of this sketch could not be determined from your code. Use
>   only number (not variables) for the size() comand. Read the size()
>   reference for more details"

Source code [here](https://codebender.cc/sketch:146643#Arduino_radar_client_processing.ino).

Answer (score 0):

- So, yeah, you do have to use actual numbers instead of variables.
- But set the surface to be resizable.
- Then set that to the image dimensions.
- Then load the image to the surface and scale it to the surface dimensions.

So, something like this:

```
  size(1, 1);
  surface.setResizable(true);
  surface.setSize(bgimage.width, bgimage.height);

  // and when you're ready to actually load the image
  image(bgimage, 0, 0, width, height);
```